# localStorage works on desktop but not mobile (iOS version 12.2)

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, local-storage

I have created a simple Todos app using React, and have implemented `localStorage` in order to persist data between page refreshes. The implementation is something like this:

```js
loadStateFromLocalStorage() {
  for (let key in this.state) {
    if (localStorage.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      let value = localStorage.getItem(key);

      try {
        value = JSON.parse(value);
        this.setState({ [key]: value });
      } catch (e) {
        // handle empty string
        this.setState({ [key]: value });
      }
    }
  }
}
saveStateToLocalStorage() {
  for (let key in this.state) {
    localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(this.state[key]));
  }
}
```

If needed, my full App.js is here (and the code is hosted on GitHub [here](https://github.com/james-work-account/react-todos)):

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Search from './components/Search.js';
import Todos from './components/Todos.js';
import Filters from './components/Filters.js';
import { TodoFilter, InitialState } from './common';
import GitHubIcon from './components/GitHubIcon.js'


class App extends Component {

  state = InitialState;

  // Local Storage
  loadStateFromLocalStorage() {
    for (let key in this.state) {
      if (localStorage.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        let value = localStorage.getItem(key);

        try {
          value = JSON.parse(value);
          this.setState({ [key]: value });
        } catch (e) {
          // handle empty string
          this.setState({ [key]: value });
        }
      }
    }
  }
  saveStateToLocalStorage() {
    for (let key in this.state) {
        localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(this.state[key]));
    }
  }

  // Lifecycle methods
  componentDidMount() {
    // Load state from localStorage
    this.loadStateFromLocalStorage();

    // Resizing page
    this.setState({width: window.innerWidth});
    window.addEventListener("resize", this.updateDimensions);

    // Set localStorage on refresh/reload
    window.addEventListener(
      "beforeunload",
      this.saveStateToLocalStorage.bind(this)
    );
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    // Remove listeners
    window.removeEventListener(
      "beforeunload",
      this.saveStateToLocalStorage.bind(this)
    );
    window.removeEventListener("resize", this.updateDimensions);

    // Save state to localStorage
    this.saveStateToLocalStorage();
  }

  updateDimensions = () => {
    this.setState({ 
      width: window.innerWidth
    });
  }

  // Add a new Todo
  handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    if(this.state.currentTodoText !== "") {
      const newTodo = {
        id: Date.now(),
        text: this.state.currentTodoText,
        checked: false
      };
      const todos = [...this.state.todos, newTodo];
      this.setState({todos});
      this.setState({currentTodoText: ""});
      document.querySelector(".search input").value = "";
    }
  }

  // Update current Todo text
  handleChange = (event) => this.setState({currentTodoText: event.target.value})

  resetData = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState({todos: InitialState.todos});
    this.setState({currentTodoText: InitialState.currentTodoText});
    this.setState({currentFilter: InitialState.currentFilter});
    document.querySelector(".search input").value = "";
  }

  // Delete a Todo
  handleDelete = (todo) => {
    const todos = this.state.todos.filter((td) => td.id !== todo.id)
    this.setState({todos})
  }

  // Check a Todo
  handleCheck = (todo) => {
    const todos = this.state.todos.map((td) => td.id === todo.id ? {...td, checked: !td.checked} : td)
    this.setState({todos})
  }

  // Change Todo filter
  handleFilter = (filter) => {
    switch (filter) {
      case TodoFilter.filterCompleted: {
        this.setState({currentFilter: TodoFilter.filterCompleted})
        break;
      }
      case TodoFilter.filterUncompleted: {
        this.setState({currentFilter: TodoFilter.filterUncompleted})
        break;
      }
      case TodoFilter.all: {
        this.setState({currentFilter: TodoFilter.all})
        break;
      }
      default: {
        this.setState({currentFilter: TodoFilter.all})
        break;
      }
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Search handleChange={this.handleChange} handleSubmit={this.handleSubmit} resetData={this.resetData}/>
        <Filters handleFilter={this.handleFilter} currentFilter={this.state.currentFilter}/>
        <Todos todos={this.state.todos.filter(
          (todo) => {
            switch (this.state.currentFilter) {
              case TodoFilter.filterCompleted: return todo.checked;
              case TodoFilter.filterUncompleted: return !todo.checked;
              case TodoFilter.all: return true;
              default: return true;
            }
          }
        )} handleDelete={this.handleDelete} handleCheck={this.handleCheck}/>
        <GitHubIcon />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

This works on desktop, but I hosted the app on Heroku<sup>[1]</sup> to see if it works on mobile too and data isn't persisting through page refreshes. Does localStorage work differently on mobile vs desktop? How do I implement localStorage to work both on my phone and my desktop?

---

<sup>[1]</sup> Since I tested the accepted answer by redeploying the app to Heroku, the link previously here no longer runs off the code which contained my issue and thus I've removed it - See the commit which fixed my issue [here](https://github.com/james-work-account/react-todos/commit/5987c4e4a6b70e58413c4af27023097a6aa4ec95).

Comment: What do you exactly mean with mobile? Local storage support is by browser and you can check it here: https://caniuse.com/#search=localstorage. Your page on heroku works for me with chrome + safari.

Comment: @Dario sorry, I use iOS Safari v12.2. That link suggests localStorage should work on my browser...

Comment: And is not working for you? If I open the page (safari 12.0.2), save some todo, refresh the page, I see them again...

Comment: No, when I refresh the page none of the data I change is saved. How peculiar...

Comment: It's not a storage issue? Older Safari versions wont store anything while in private mode, and you only got a limited amount to store when using localStorage. 5-10Mb depending on browser.

Comment: Maybe you can try to see if it works with cookies

Comment: @RickardElimää I'm using the latest version of Safari on my phone, and my state isn't exactly huge... to avoid pasting loads of code in the comments you can see here what it looks like initially: https://github.com/james-work-account/react-todos/blob/master/src/common.js#L7-L16

Comment: I'm on Android 9.0. Google Chrome mobile v73.0.3683.90. I can open the page, save a todo, close tab, open page again, and the todos still exist.

Comment: Maybe it's a Safari thing then... Or my phone is just bugging out... I guess I'll have to do some further digging. Thanks guys.

Comment: Why don't you try on Chrome instead of Safari

Comment: I've just tested with Firefox and Chrome (both latest versions on the iOS App Store) and it doesn't seem to be working on those either. It looks like it's either an iOS thing or a my-phone-isn't-behaving thing...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the problem, `beforeunload` safari mobile does not support this event.
Look this docs [Events/beforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/zh-CN/docs/Web/Events/beforeunload)

Comment: Good find. The OP should just update `localStorage` on every `componentDidUpdate` when `prevState.todos !== state.todos`

Comment: I've just redeployed my app to Heroku with `this.saveStateToLocalStorage()` in `componentDidUpdate()` rather than having it sit on the `beforeunload` event listener, and that seems to have done the trick. Good spot!