# Detect iPod or Iphone using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a scenario in which I need to detect whether the device is an iPod or iPhone. navigator.userAgent/navigator.platform doesn't have device information.

Comment: `var isIphone = navigator.userAgent.indexOf("iPhone") != -1 ;`
`var isIod = navigator.userAgent.indexOf("iPod") != -1 ;`
`var isIpad = navigator.userAgent.indexOf("iPad") != -1 ;`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect if device is iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9038625/detect-if-device-is-ios)

Comment: https://developers.whatismybrowser.com/useragents/explore/operating_platform/ipod/ suggests the user agent features `iPod` quite prominently, so … what’s the actual issue?

Comment: "I need to detect whether the device is an iPod or iPhone" — Why? Usually what you need to detect is "Is the screen size small" or "Does this device have a touch screen" or "What is the right app store link for this device?". What's the real problem?

Comment: @Quentin only thing I can think of is that Safari mobile doesn't support certain lifecycle events ([I've been bitten by that in the past](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55745145/8230810))... or maybe for advertising purposes?

Comment: @JamesWhiteley—which is where feature detection comes in.

Comment: Please see [*Browser detection using the user agent*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Browser_detection_using_the_user_agent), which also applies to device detection.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I use to detect iOS devices:

```
function is_little_ithing() {
    return (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('iPod') > -1 ||
    navigator.userAgent.indexOf('iPhone') > -1);
}

function is_big_ithing() {
    return (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('iPad') > -1);
}

function is_ithing() {
    return (is_little_ithing() || is_big_ithing());
}
```

Comment: Which will include Apple watches running WatchOS as an iOS device, or any user agent string that includes 'iPod' or 'iPhone'. Android might decide that it's being discriminated against by such UA sniffing, so include iPad or iPhone in its browser's UA string. User agent sniffing is renowned as a poor strategy for detecting either browsers or devices.